# Unable to MudDatePicker how to bind it to a Datamodel

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

```
<EditForm Model="@_newRegister" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  <ValidationSummary />
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <MudDatePicker Label="Collection Date" Editable="true" @bind-Date="_newRegister.CollectionDate" />
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Editform>

@code{
private Register _newRegister = new x.Shared.Register
{
    ProcessingDate = DateTime.Today,
    CollectionDate = DateTime.Today,
    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Today
};

private string Success = "";
DateTime? date = DateTime.Today;

public void HandleValidSubmit()
{

    Success = "Success";

}
)
```

---

```
public class Register
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessingDate { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public String Remarks { get; set; }
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

}
```

'''

i am getting this error .. if i use a local datetime variable (date) this error is gone, however i am not able to mapp that to the model anymore ..  Any solution how to do i bind the model on this

> Error CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate
> type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return type X.Client
>
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.DateTime>' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'   x.Client
> D:\x\Client\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\CashRegister\AddRegister.razor.g.cs  174 Active
>
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.DateTime>' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'       D:\x\Client\Pages\CashRegister\AddRegister.razor
> Error  CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate
> type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return
> type      D:\x\Client\Pages\CashRegister\AddRegister.razor

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party by about 8 months, but the answer is you need to bind to a nullable `DateTime`.

So your property needs to be `public DateTime? CollectionDate { get; set; }` and it should work. I just had the same problem.

Also their API says

> Note: Always use the two-way binding @bind-Date to bind to a field of
> type DateTime?

See: https://www.mudblazor.com/components/datepicker#basic-usage